# Laravel custom error message after submitting the data and redirecting to the same page with some little error info

Tags: php, html, laravel

So basically my plan ist to make my application simpler. If a user wants to lend a lot of books it could be that the user scans the same book again and the page which i get ist the following:

https://gyazo.com/e7236fec2cfc745d604d7eced2a1e333

or use this:

[image]

I know that this is the production and not the development mode of laravel. So how can i redirect the page whith an error info for the user so he can understand that he scanned the book twice? So i just want to transfrom the database issue error messages to a simple redirect and a message but how can i reach this goal?`

At first i give you my view code:

```
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
    <!--  <script> setTimeout(function(){window.location=localhost:8000/}, 5); </script> -->
          <br>
          <br>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('lend book') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('borrow.store') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="serialnumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Bitte serialnumber scannen') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('serialnumber'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('serialnumber') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="ma_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('scan membercard to identify yourself') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                              <input id="ma_id" type="password" class="form-control" name="ma_id" required>


                              @if ($errors->has('ma_id'))
                              <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('ma_id') }}</strong>
                              </span>
                              @endif
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="comment" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('comment') }}</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">

                            <input id="comment" type="text-field" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Test">


                            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        </div>




                      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('send') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 @endsection
```

This is my Controller code:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    request()->validate([
      'seriennummer' => 'required',
      'ma_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    borrow::create($request->all());


    return redirect()->route('borrow.index')
                     ->with('success','Proccess succesfully');

}
```

So what i tried was to change the return to the following:

```
redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

or

```
 return back()->with('autofocus', true);
```

and the view like this:

```
<input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" required   @if (Session::has('autofocus')) autofocus @endif>
```

Can anybody help me to get this right? Or have anybody some ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you're having issues when validating then I suppose what you're looking for is: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators Because using `request()->validate(...)` will redirect the user automagically back to form page. PS: see `request()->only(['seriennummer','ma_id'])` is more appropriate than `request()->all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `php artisan make:request BookRequest`  in your root project folder (CMD);

Add the new request to your function in your **controller**, so it will look like this:

```
use App\Http\Requests\BookRequest

Class BookController extends Controller
{
    ...      

    public function store (BookRequest $request)
    {
        <Your code here, you do not need to worry about validation, it is done previous of calling store now! If it fails it redirects automatically to the previous page!>
        ... Your logic to add the book into the DB...
    }
    ...
}
```

Your **BookRequest Class** located at `App\Http\Requests`:

```
Class BookRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        <You can add here authorization like if user is authenticated. If you do not wish so, and just make it available just return TRUE>

        return TRUE;
    }        

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'seriennummer' => 'required|unique',
            'ma_id' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'seriennummer.required' => 'You need to select a book',
            'seriennummer.unique' => 'Seems like you have added the same book more than once!',
        ... Your other fields you wish to validate. This fields are declared on the form!...
       ];
    }
```

}

At your **view**:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer but the documentation dont help me at all thats why i posted the question here cause i dont know how to get this done.

Comment: No worries! But is it your desire to go back to the page your customer submitted the information from and display the error message or to just halt execution and present an error page, not allowing to try and change anything? Like a 500 would be treated?

Comment: It would be okay if it shows an error after submitting and then it shows something like "You added the same book twice please go back and try again"

Comment: Right, I will be updating my answer with all the steps you need to take on your code to set this to work. Within it I will do it as a list of errors so it displayes the custom messages and, if you have more than one, it just list them.

I will also be assuming you are using bootstrap for this which will speed up your display :) Bear with me while I update it

Comment: I big thanks to you that really helps me oout and yes i am using bootstrap :)

Comment: If you execute the artisan command it will set your Request class in the right location and activate the required settings for you. So all you need to do is follow the above steps with your logic. It should be good to go! :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help! ^^
I forgot to mention you can specify messages based on the error type `unique`, `required`, etc.

I updated the answer again for you to check on this in case different scenarios come along! Check the `public function messages()` Changes to consider this :)

Comment: Just one more question mister >.< You said its easy to add more so what could it look like when a serialnumber isnt in the database just in case ? As example you scan the ean instead of the serial number or something like this

Comment: If the number is not on the DB and you are targetting the `store()` function, it means you wish to add it to the DB! :) Or isn't that the case?

Comment: When the number isnt in the database it gives an database error which is correct i just want to make it like the other which you already explained so when the customer has an book which isnt registered it should say something like "Please go to our information to get further instructions what to do" or something like that. everything would be fine i just dont want that the customer get an sql error some bootstrap information box would be better

Comment: You really dont have to say how i could do it i botherd you enough i just want to know if i could implement it to the code above

Comment: Yes, you can check that within your `public function store()` functionality :)
If you have access to your Model, let's say it is `Book` then you can check in the DB to see if it exists:
   `if( !Book::find($request->get('seriennummer'))->exists() ) {`

Notice how I consider your `seriennummer` to be the DB ID! If such is not the case, you can use the `where` clause instead ^^
It checks to see if it does not exists, and within the `if` you can do what behaviour your logic needs

Comment: I had this error while trying to implement it to the public store function in the controller :/ -> call to a member function on null

Comment: Can you share the code you implemented to give me a better idea?
It might be worth it to open a new ticket as it seems to be a different subject now :) To keep implementations and question clean

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
...
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'seriennummer' => 'required|unique',
   'ma_id' => 'required'
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
}
```

and on the view

```
@if ($errors->has('seriennummer'))
    <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('seriennummer') }}</strong></span>
@endif
```

Comment: I get this Error message....BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fails does not exist.

Comment: add the reference to the facade, place `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` on top of your file